# list blogs list of blogger in Google PHP SDK

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using `Google API SDK` in CakePHP application.

I have to list the blogs owned by the user after authenticating the application.

The user will select from the list of blogs and I will record the blog ID to make further requests.

According to the documentation, we need to make GET request to

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

But I have my API Key and user's access token.

**How can I list the blogs using the access token?**

I tried using the SDK Services

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(GOOGLE_APP_NAME);
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);

$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger');

$callback_url = Router::url(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'controller' => 'SharingLogin', 'action' => 'bloggerCallback'], true);

$client->setRedirectUri($callback_url);

$service = new \Google_Service_Blogger($client);
$listblog = $service->blogs;

debug($listblog);
```

But this lists nothing and empty array object.